# Is ASP.NET MVC 5 incompatible with the WebMatrix SimpleMembershipProvider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

We have an existing application that was build on ASP.NET MVC 4 & Web API. The admin parts of the site use Simple Membership. I'm interested in upgrading the application to MVC 5 / Web API 2, to take advantage of some of the new features that have been added. But it looks like they might be incompatible.

Specifically, after installing the RC packages from NuGet into one of the projects in my solution, and [updating the web.config information](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2), the application starts dying during startup on the line that calls `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection()`, with this exception:

```
[MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.OnConnectionOpened(System.Object, WebMatrix.Data.ConnectionEventArgs)' to access security critical method 'System.Web.WebPages.HttpContextExtensions.RegisterForDispose(System.Web.HttpContextBase, System.IDisposable)' failed.]
   WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.OnConnectionOpened(Object sender, ConnectionEventArgs e) +70
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.OnConnectionOpened() +70
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen() +51
   WebMatrix.Data.Database.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] args) +63
   WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QueryValue(String commandText, Object[] parameters) +13
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.GetUserId(IDatabase db, String userTableName, String userNameColumn, String userIdColumn, String userName) +206
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.ValidateUserTable() +87
```

Other projects in the same solution using Simple Membership that I have *not* upgraded continue to work just fine.

Googling around for more information turns up lots of hits for that exception, of course, but nothing particular to WebMatrix.

FWIW: I know that Microsoft has introduced [(yet another) membership and identity solution](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/27/introducing-asp-net-identity-membership-system-for-asp-net-applications.aspx), but unless there's a way to use that with the existing Simple Membership tables, or a seamless migration path for all of our existing user data, that's not really an option for us.

## UPDATE (11 Oct)

I just tried this again with a fresh checkout of the current trunk of our app. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, but otherwise followed the instructions from MS for upgrading an existing project. After updating to MVC 5 / Web API 2 / EF 6, the app started up an ran just fine.

There were no explicit trust requirements in the `web.config` to remove. I added the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically) to `Global.asax.cs`, and it reports that the app is running with full trust (in IIS Express, just F5-ed from VS).

Re-adding the same call to `InitializeDatabaseConnection()`, it starts dying with the exact same exception.

## SOLUTION (28 Oct)

Trying the solution in @Kevin's update from Friday, I found that it works. It was really strange to me that adding this apparently unrelated package would solve these security issues, and even *more* strange after I removed the package from my solution, and it *kept working*.

Taking a closer look at what was happening, I realized that the reason why this fixes the behavior is quite simple: the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers` package has two dependencies that were being added to my solution: `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData`. **Microsoft has moved the WebMatrix classes into new packages.**

So added the helpers package fixed the problem, not because of anything it was doing, but because **it was causing updated versions of the broken assemblies to be added** to my solution. The solution to the initial incompatibility, then, is to install these new packages when updating everything else from NuGet:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData
```

## UPDATE (13 May 2015)

It has been [suggested to me](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8047475) that you may also need to manually install the second new package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data
```

This *should not* be necessary, because this package is [an explicit dependency](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData/) of the first, and NuGet should be smart enough to install both. But if you get [an error when building](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23181104/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-webmatrix-data-version-3-0-0-0), or don't see NuGet add the dependency, it might help you.

Comment: I wish I could vote this up more than once, thank you, thank you, thank you for going through the trouble to document your process. I was about to enter panic mode. You saved me from being embarrassed in this mornings presentation.

Comment: I also had to actually remove webmatrix from my project references. The uninstall of those packages and install of webhelpers didn't do that part for me.

Comment: Thank you so much. Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.WebData works for me

Answer (score 36, accepted):

WebMatrix is compatible with MVC 5.

What I did was to take an empty MVC 5 project and incorporate WebMatrix SimpleMembershipProvider into it using [SimpleSecurity](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/), an open source project that [decouples SimpleMembership from your MVC application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html). So far I am able to create the database, seed it, and log in and out.  I plan on adding other features to this reference application, such as email confirmation and various tests.  When I am done I will post the source code in the [SimpleSecurity Project](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest)

If I had to guess, your problem may be with the upgrade process.  What process did you take to upgrade your MVC 4 project to MVC 5?  [Did you follow this process](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2)? What version of the WebMatrix assemblies are you using? What version of Visual Studio are you using? I am using version 2.0.0.0 of WebMatrix and Visual Studio 2013 RC.

---

**Update (10/25/2013)**

I continued my experiment with adding SimpleMembership to an MVC 5 project and somewhere along the line it broke and I got the same results as @Sixten Otto. I did not test incrementally as I added things but I am suspicious it may have happened when I installed the Web API assemblies.  They are not installed by default when creating a new MVC 5 project.

I did some more research on the error and came across this QA titled "[Attempt by security transparent method 'WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17926552/attempt-by-security-transparent-method-webmatrix-webdata-preapplicationstartcod)". This is an old QA and originally someone was getting this same error when upgrading an MVC 3 app to MVC 4.  But recently people have been adding answers in regards to upgrading to MVC 5 and one of the answers worked for me.  **The solution for me was install the NuGet package *Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers*.**  After installing this package everything worked fine.

A note about my research into migrating to the new ASP.NET Identity is that they do not use the same password hash, which precludes moving old members into a database used by ASP.NET Identity.  ASP.NET Identity seems to be in real flux right now so maybe they will come up with a solution for this.

---

**Update (2/16/14)**

I erroneously reported that the hash algorithm for passwords was different in SimpleMembership and ASP.NET Identity. I assumed this based on a visual inspection of the hashed passwords, assuming that it was just the hashed password that was in the fields.  After further research I found that SimpleMembership uses the System.Web.Helpers.Crypto class for hashing the password and what is stored in the password field is actually a 256 bit subkey and the salt.  With that information I ran some tests to validate that ASP.NET Identity can verify passwords that are generated by SimpleMembership, and it passed.  I was trying to find out what hash algorithm SimpleMembership used so I could plug in a password hasher in ASP.NET Identity that would allow me to migrate data from a SimpleMembership webiste to one that used ASP.NET Identity. Turns out it is not necessary. [I talk about the password hash and how to migrate the data from SimpleMembership to ASP.NET Identity in more detail in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2014/02/migrating-existing-website-from.html).

Comment: VS 2012, WebMatrix 2.0.0.0. Did follow those instructions (and linked to the same post in my question). Did your empty project also include Web API? Can you account for the security exception I'm seeing?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the link in your question that is the same link I referenced. I did not need to follow these instructions since I started with an MVC 5 project.  When I complete my empty project it will include Web API to test a custom AuthorizeAttribute.  Since I have not taken the upgrade path you did, all I have verified is that WebMatrix can work with MVC 5 in Visual Studio 2013, so there is some hope. As for the security exception; are you sure your application is running in full trust?

Comment: I'm not: how would I be able to tell? My understanding is that's the default, and I haven't done anything to explicitly change any security settings. Ran fine before the upgrade, or without attempting to initialize SimpleMembership. Just running in IIS Express locally from VS.

Comment: There seems to be something about needing full trust in MVC 5 applications as stated in item 4 in "Update the Application web.config File" section of the article you referenced. The error you are seeing can be caused by an application not running in full trust.  Check out this QA to see if it helps [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090494/how-to-confirm-a-web-site-is-running-in-full-trust].

Comment: Again, it was my understanding that that was the default trust level, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be. This looks like more directly applicable code to answer the "is it?" question when I get the chance to re-run the experiment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064274/get-current-asp-net-trust-level-programmatically

Comment: Please look at my updated answer and see if the solution that worked for me will work in your situation.

Comment: I was able to get my test working by following your steps, and I'll give you the answer. But it does *not* appear that the `WebHelpers` package itself is necessary: only its dependencies.

Comment: @Kevin Junghans, Is WebMatrix not compatible with MVC 6 any more?

Answer (score 30):

If you are getting the error

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   ‘WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()’ to access security
>   critical method
>   ‘System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebPageRazorHost.AddGlobalImport(System.String)’
>   failed.

In order to fix this install this package using NuGet package manager.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers
```

After that , probably you will get another error

> Cannot load WebMatrix.Data version 3.0.0.0 assembly

to fix this install this package using NuGet package manager.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data
```

Answer (score 3):

We are currently working on a migration doc for migrating from Simple Membership to ASP.NET Identity. Please stay tuned for a couple of weeks until we push this migration doc.
For now you have to map your Simple Membership schema to Identity and change your application code to use OWIN for SignIN/ SIgnOut

Comment: Does this imply that the password hashing used by the new ASP.NET Identity system is (or can be configured to be) the same as that done by SimpleMembership? Worst comes to worst, we could script the database changes to move the existing data into new tables and such. But if we can't continue to use existing credentials, then the schema changes are irrelevant.

Comment: The [tutorial on migrating from the older SQL Membership](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/migrations/migrating-an-existing-website-from-sql-membership-to-aspnet-identity) is up. Looks like the solution there was to provide a custom hashing service that literally copy-pastes the code from the older provider, and uses either that or the default Identity implementation, depending on the format of the hashed password string in the database. Should we assume that the solution for Simple Membership will be the same? (Guess it's a good thing that the WebMatrix source code is public, huh?)

Comment: Any progress on this document? It has been a lot more than "a couple of weeks" and the only migration guide I saw is one for migrating from SQL Membership -- not from SimpleMembership.

Comment: We have posted a sample on how you can migrate from Simple Membership to ASP.NET Identity. https://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest Look at Identity folder in the sources and you will see two samples. Simplemembership MigrationSchemaUpdate shows you how to migrate an app using simple membership and change the schema to match ASP.NET Identity. SimpleMembershipMigration shows how you can plug in your existing schema that you created using Simple Membership and use ASP.NET Identity features.

Answer (score 3):

The above answers worked not until recent webpages 3.2.3. A new issue showed up for me. The current fix for me was by upgrading to .Net 4.5.3. I figured this out of frustration. This issue doesnt just affect MVC 5 but core Webmatrix projects as well after upgrading to webpages 3.2.3. I think it is a framework issue that will be fixed with the new Microsoft Identity. The current fix for me is below:
*Note: Please use the property pages wizard in visual studio to change your target framework to .Net Framework 4.5.3. It will update your web.config*

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.3">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Step 1: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHelpers

Step 2: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.Data

Step 3: [Optional] Install-Package Owin

Step 4: Change targetFramework to .Net 4.5.3 via Property pages dialog box

[image]

[Optionally] Your Web.Config should look like the below

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add connectionString="Server=XTREMEGOSPEL;Database=portfolioDB;Trusted_Connection=True" name="portDB" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.Web>
  -->
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.3">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="1440"/>
    </authentication>
    <sessionState timeout="1440"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem, not at my local computer but live site was having that.

I removed below lines from web config and it is working now.

```
<dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```