# In MVC5, where has the configuration site gone?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to setup roles for the users of my MVC5 site.  The only information I've been able to find are MVC4 information, where they use the configuration site to add/manage roles.

However I can't find it anymore.  I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Where is this site gone ?  And if it doesn't exist anymore, how can I configure the roles ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Here it is the [stackoverflow topic about mvc-5 and webmatrix-SimpleMembershipProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169846/is-asp-net-mvc-5-incompatible-with-the-webmatrix-simplemembershipprovider)  where the similar problem is discribed. They provide simple membership with WebMatrix and it's simple membership and roles providers. Have a lookup,I think it would help!!!

Comment: Thanks, but I would really like to use the new Identity system, not SimpleMembership.  In the meantime, I used verification based on login name (it's really a small site targetted at my close entourage, so it doesn't matter).

Comment: Actually Simple membership allows you to provide your own roles. By the way, you can still write your own membership provider! There are many guidelines, if you would search in google how to do it on mvc 4, so you can try impliment it in your mvc 5 code. Sorry that my anwer did't help much