# Using ASP Identity over SimpleMembership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I currently have a MVC 4 app with `SimpleMembership`, which works well. I feelt though that I might as well update now to MVC 5, while I am still developing rather than later.

I am wondering if it would be more practical to stay with `SimpleMembership` or move to `ASP Identity`. I have read that it is possible to get `SimpleMembership` to work. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169846/is-asp-net-mvc-5-incompatible-with-the-webmatrix-simplemembershipprovider)

I would have no problem moving to `ASP Identity` if I hadn't read that it forced the developer to implement most of the features older versions had themselves. Such as Login Attempts and Confirming Email. [Here is one place this is stated](http://brockallen.com/2013/10/20/the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly-of-asp-net-identity/#ugly)

There may have been changes to `ASP Identity` since these posts, but I have a hard time finding documentation on it.

Any advice or personal experiences would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source [SimpleSecurity Project](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/) provides good examples on implementing features such as [email confirmation](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html) using ASP.NET Identity.  This project also provides an example of [using SimpleMembership in MVC 5](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/upgrading-web-application-using.html) and helps you through some of the hurdles I hit when trying to upgrade to MVC 5.  The implementation of ASP.NET Identity in the [SimpleSecurity project decouples it from the web application](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/11/decoupling-aspnet-identify-from-your.html) and provides an API similar to the WebSecurity class you are familiar with from using SimpleMembership.  SimpleSecurity gives you both options with MVC 5, but since you are making the effort to upgrade to MVC 5 and you are still in development I would also make the effort to upgrade to ASP.NET Identity as this is the future of identity and access control in ASP.NET.