# Piranha CMS error on Azure websites

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, piranha-cms

Using the prerelease 2.2 version of Piranha CMS, MVC 5 and EF 6.02 and publishing to an Azure website, I receive the following error: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.  see screen shot below.

http://screencast.com/t/PxwhtJd7xx8n

Please advise on how to correct this issue.  Everything works properly locally.

**UPDATE**

After using remote debugging I was able to determine that Piranha is attempting to load WebMatrix.WebData and cannot find it.
http://screencast.com/t/5qytkgqmeaV6

Setting copy local to true produces a few additional load errors so that is only part of the issue.

Comment: this usually means that there is an assembly that is local but VS doesn't copy it over when it builds the project, and after you publish to the remote site it can't find that assembly. Can you make sure that all the non .NET Framework assemblies are marked as Copy Local True in VS before publishing

Answer (score 0):

After digging around a bit, I found this SO article
[Is ASP.NET MVC 5 incompatible with the WebMatrix SimpleMembershipProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169846/is-asp-net-mvc-5-incompatible-with-the-webmatrix-simplemembershipprovider)
The suggestion to install Microsoft.AspNet.Helpers seemed to do the trick (along with setting the copy local to true on the WebMatrix dlls.)