# Simple Membership gives me Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, simplemembership

I am trying to add ASP.NET Simple Membership to my MVC 5 application. When the application start the initialization part in Global.asax.cs - Application_Start() gives me the following error:

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

I'm initializing the membership by calling

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("CareerEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
```

I have following connection string (I'm using Entity framework Database first)

```
<add name="CareerEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Career.csdl|res://*/Models.Career.ssdl|res://*/Models.Career.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=Career;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I tried to change the provider name to be "System.Data.SqlClient" but it didn't work either

Comment: Check this : http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/11/entity-framework-6-sql-server-compact-4_25.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19169846/is-asp-net-mvc-5-incompatible-with-the-webmatrix-simplemembershipprovider)

Also I had a mistake that i should define the Default connection with "System.Data.SqlClient" and the other Entity framework connection "System.Data.EntityClient"