# Unable to find .net data provider exception when implementing SimpleMembership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

I am a newbie. I am using `SimpleMembership` to generate the Register and login tables. However, I am getting the following exception.

EXCEPTION

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework
>   Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

[image]

CODE

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Register1()
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {


            //WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("My_Entities", "Users", "Id", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("My_Entities", "User", "Id", "Email", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
        return View("Register");
    }
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register1(FormCollection form)
    {
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(form["username"], form["password"], new { DisplayName = form["displayname"], Country = form["country"] });
        Response.Redirect("~/account/login");
        return View();
    }
```

**WEB.CONFIG**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="p1">
      <providers>
        <add name="p1" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <add name="p1" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MY_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.DB.csdl|res://*/Models.DB.ssdl|res://*/Models.DB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYCOMP\MYCOM;initial catalog=MY;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=1*34;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797823/simple-membership-gives-me-unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-prov#answer-21804341

Comment: Yes I did. But I didn't understand the solution. If you can elaborate a bit.

Comment: You need to have proper SQL Server (and Entity Framework) connection string(s) in `web.config` file when using `SimpleMembershipProvider`. Check if corresponding data provider had installed properly.

Comment: I have added my `WEB.CONFIG` file in the post. Can someone tell me what should I add. Sorry, I am a newbie.

Comment: Seems that you've missing SQL Server connection string in `<connectionStrings>` element. You need to add connection string like `<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="data source=MYCOMP\MYCOM;initial catalog=MY;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=1*34"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />` at same place with EF connection string.

Comment: It's still the same. I have the same exception as before.

Comment: Find `machine.config` file and try removing self terminating element `<DbProviderFactories />` if exists. Probably you have problem with database provider factory instead of missing connection string.

Comment: I think I had a problem with the connection String. If you can add that as an answer, I can then accept it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130194/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-illep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provided `web.config` file gives presence of `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` as Entity Framework's data provider on this part:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

Since the error clearly said that the requested data provider is not yet installed, find out `machine.config` file in `%Windows%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version number]\Config`, edit it in admin privileges then add these lines below (or if you're being lazy to dig up machine.config, place them into web.config under `system.data` element):

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
        <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Also, remove any single-terminating element of `<DbProviderFactories />` if you found them.

Next, you may adding references related to SQL Server CE (`sqlce*.dll`) using Package Manager Console by finding `EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` package (refer [this one](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/)) and install it on your solution. Additionally, change provider name `System.Data.SqlClient` to `System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0` in EF (and SQL Server) connection string when required.

References:

[Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/93549e61-9868-4549-b440-96a65a822ba1/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider?forum=sqlce)

[Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/12/19/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-installed/)

[Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed. - when following mvc3 asp.net tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865249/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install)

Answer (score 0):

Please try add the following configure settings in your web.config.

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
    <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```